# Activeadmin Formtastic custom input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

I have a simple app, which has three models `Assessment`, `Question` and `AssessmentQuestion`

In `Assessment` i have the association like,

```
class Assessment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assessment_questions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :questions, through: :assessment_questions
end
```

In `Question` i have,

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assessment_questions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :bank_questions, dependent: :destroy
end
```

In `AssessmentQuestion` i have,

```
class AssessmentQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :assessment
end
```

assessment_questions table has `:assessment_id`, `:question_id` and `:mark` columns

I have admin interface using `ActiveAdmin` gem.

While creating assessments in admin interface, In admin/assessment.rb i have a form generated by the formtastic gem,

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :name
      f.input :duration
      f.input :questions, as: :check_boxes, member_label: :id
      f.input :creator_id
    end

    f.actions :commit
  end
```

[image: Screen shot of that page]

This looks fine and no problem. The thing that i want is while choosing questions through the checkboxes, i want a textbox below or side to each checkbox containing mark of the questions will be filled in text boxes respectively ( through `question.assessment_question.mark` association ), so that i can edit the prefilled marks of the questions while creating assessment or leave it as it is.

I have tried, but got some error like

```
undefined method `to_sym' for {:for=>:questions}:Hash
```

My code,

```
form do |f|
        f.inputs do
          f.input :name
          f.input :duration
          f.input for: :questions do | question |
            f.input :question, as: :select
            f.input question.assessment_question.mark
           end 
          f.input :creator_id
        end

        f.actions :commit
      end
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, i figured it out.

I actually created a custom `semantic_form_for` form `_form.html.erb` as a partial and included this in admin/assessment.rb file

```
form partial: 'assessment/form'
```

That's how i solved.

Reference: http://activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html

Answer (score 1):

I would make a custom input that contains a checkbox and a string input:

https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic#modified--custom-inputs

Answer (score -3):

The solution is obvious, your "f.input :for" misses an "s".
It should be f.inputs